# " Building Javascript bundle: finished in ms" runs again and again in React-native with expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I follow a tutorial to develop a react native mobile app. Once I try to run the app code using expo, the following statement runs again and again without displaying the app;  Building Javascript bundle: finished in xxxms runs again and again. This is my app code. As I am a beginner to react native,  if someone could help me to find this issue I really appreciate your help. Thank You.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Login from './src/pages/Login';

export default class App extends Component() {
  render() { 

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      //setting the statusbar color
      <StatusBar 
      backgroundColor= '#961c44'
      barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <Login/>    //Displaying the Login
    </View>
  );
  }
}

//adding styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ff8c00',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Login.js  - This file creates under a folder called pages in src

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component() {
  render() {
      return (
          <View>
              <Text>Login</Text>
          </View>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: hey , does your app display after few minutes or continously says that bundling javascript?

Comment: @GauravRoy, no it continously says that bundling javascript and at some point it stops, but app is not displayed